# Replace function set as Store Procedure or Function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

How can I convert my replace function as a stored procedure or function in MySQL?

Here is a simplified update script:

```
mysql> UPDATE content SET url = REPLACE (url, 'testsite', 'livesite') WHERE URL LIKE '%testsite%';
```

I want to be able to store this and run this function via a query.

My goal is to to something like this:

```
CALL myupdatefunction ('testsite', 'livesite', @url);
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateURL(OUT url1, OUT url2)
BEGIN 
   UPDATE content SET url = REPLACE (url, url1, url2) WHERE URL LIKE url1;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And to CALL

```
CALL updateURL('stringOld','stringNew');
```

Not sure if this is the right approach?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: @MarcB, forgot to add my trial. Thanks for reviewing this.

Comment: your procedure is defined with only two parameters, but you're calling it with 3...

Comment: @MarcB - The ***system*** function `REPLACE` is being called with three parameters, one coming from the table being updated.  The ***user defined function*** `updateURL` is still being called with two parameters.   *[In the final code example at least, I think the OPs first example went a bit wonky.]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make a little change, you have to add the percent sign in the `like` expression

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateURL(OUT url1, OUT url2)
BEGIN 
   UPDATE content SET url = REPLACE (url, url1, url2) WHERE URL LIKE CONCAT('%', url1, '%');
END //
DELIMITER ;
```